# batch: Comparing with the result of a question [y/n]

Tags: batch-file

The first page or so of google or stack overflow has resulted in comparing variables against variables. But I'm not even there yet. Here's my code, see how simple it is, and yet I cannot for the life of me get it working as expected.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p isFirst= "First time setup? [y/n]: "
if (%isFirst% == y) (
    ECHO "First time setup." 
    CALL npm install
)

SET /p url= "Enter Base URL: "
ECHO Setting base URL to: %url%
CALL docker-compose down
CALL npm run build
CALL docker-compose build
CALL docker-compose up -d
pause
pause
```

I tried:

```
if ("%isFirst%" == "y")
if ("%isFirst%" == 'y')
if ("%isFirst%" == y)
if (%isFirst% == y)

SET %isFirstTrue% = "y"
if ("%isFirst%" == %isFirstTrue%)
```

Nothing. None of those worked. None of those ECHO'ed out `First time setup`. And yet the latter can echo out the result of `url` just fine. I assume comparing it with something later down the line will cause the same issue.

What I could have done in python over my lunch break I needed help with on batch. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps, for the correct syntax it's a good idea to read the command help first. `IF ?`,  `set /?`. Or even read other batch files tio get an idea what the correct syntax could be, guessing is the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, well, other batch files I've seen are doing %string1% == %string2 comparisons.

Comment: And why do you try it with brackets? I never saw them in working compare expressions

Comment: Force of habit.

Comment: For Yes/No prompts you should consider to use the [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) -- but read its documentation first then (type `choice /?`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` command with the `/P` option accepts no input, *(enter/return key)*, or absolutely anything at all, which includes poison characters. I advise that you do not use the `set` command for known single digit character input. That is exactly what the built-in `choice` command was designed for. Please enter `choice /?` to read the usage information for the command.

Example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "First time setup"
If Not ErrorLevel 2 (
    Echo First time setup.
    Call "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm.cmd" install
)
Rem Rest of code goes here
```

***Note:*** Please modify the location of your `npm` batch file on line `5` if I have guessed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I missed that batch doesn't like if statements in parenthesis.

`IF %isFirst% == "y"` also doesn't work.

`%isFirst% == y` does.